# Using "mv" or "ditto" to merge folders in OS X

Tags: macos, mv

Used to the Windows way of doing I just found out OS X has no merge function – moving means replacing the folder. While this does make sense, I miss merging!

---

I've two Wordpress directories, 1 contains default source and 2 contains worked version with plugins custom theme etc.

I want to see difference between this two, so I'm putting it on SVN. Folder 1 is already up, now in theory I should simply merge contents of 2 with 1 by replacing everything with contents of 2 but leaving hidden SVN files untouched.

Unfortunately OS X, when moving, replaces the folder so that my SVN client goes crazy and doesn't understand folder structure anymore.

So, I believe my options are `mv` and `ditto`, but which one would you use in my situation and how?

```
sudo mv wordpress /Documents/svn/wwwholiday/trunk/wordpress
```

I want `mv` to overwrite everything it finds, but leave alone whatever is already inside folder 1 and has no duplicate in folder 2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The easiest way to merge folders in one way, e.g.

> Merge everything from folder 1 → folder 2

would be to use `rsync`.

```
rsync -avh folder1/* folder2/
```

This will:

- move all files that only exist in folder 1 and its subdirectories to folder 2
- *not* overwrite anything in folder 2 if it's already there
- overwrite files that have been changed, *unless* you add the `--ignore-existing` option
- not delete anything from folder 2, *unless* you add the `--delete` option

Feel free to adapt this to your situation (where `folder1` and `folder2` are the other way round, I guess).

You can try to see what the command does by calling:

```
rsync -avh --dry-run folder1/ folder2/
```

The `dry-run` switch shows you what it does.

---

Don't forget that the backslashes have a special meaning, so `folder2/` as the destination is not the same as `folder2`. Check the manpage of `rsync` for usage and more options.

Also recommended is `-P` (according to `--help`, `same as --partial --progress`) which adds `show progress during transfer` and `keep partially transferred files` (which is useful for retries if there was a failure).

Comment: But I do need command overwrite files. Folder 2 contains updated php files. Which need to be written over folder 1 content. Just want to retain folder 1 svn files.

Comment: I'm sorry, of course files that have been changed will be overwritten by that command. Only files that have not been changed are skipped entirely. As long as your source folder doesn't contain SVN files, you're set.

Comment: @killermist The OP specifically wanted to keep SVN files as they are, which is why I included the wildcard *on purpose*, since without the dotglob option it'll just skip SVN directories. Of course you can exclude them from rsync by other means, but … this is for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as @slhck says or you could also just use `cp`.

```
$sudo cp -R wordpress/ /Documents/svn/wwwholiday/trunk/wordpress
```

Comment: This creates a copy of `wordpress` *within* `/Documents/svn/wwwholiday/trunk/wordpress`. Did you mean `wordpress/`?

Comment: Not fixed. *If the **source_file** ends in a /, the contents of the directory are copied rather than the directory itself.*

Comment: Isn't that what the OP wants?

Comment: Well, yes, but you added the `/` to the *target*, not the *source*.